# Effect Certain Column/column ranges in a VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on the VBA code down below to change the color of a cell based on the text specified in the certain cell. I have gotten the code to work inside the active sheet, but when I run my code it erases all colors that I had in my original spreadsheet(Not Sure Why). I would like to just apply this code to certain columns in my table.
EX only change the colors for these values in columns P and Y between rows 12- 1000...

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub changeColor()

    Dim itm As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

    For Each itm In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1)
        If Not IsError(itm) Then
            With itm
                Select Case .Value2
                    Case "GREEN", "green", "Green"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen
                    Case "RED", "red", "Red"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
                    Case "Yellow", "yellow", "Yellow"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbYellow
                End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: PS thank you to the person who shared this piece of code

Comment: `For Each itm In ActiveSheet.Range("P12:Y1000")` for example

Answer (score 0):

@ "but when I run my code it erases all colors that I had in my original spreadsheet(Not Sure Why)."

This line is saying, every cell in the used range, erase that color:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
```

Then use what Tim Williams said above in comment, to specify what range of cells to loop through.